# Django admin update a value automatically when some value is updated

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

In my model below, I want to automatically update the value of `previous_location` when the value of `location` is updated **inside django administration**. How do I implement this? Thank you in advance.

```
class Finder(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    location = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    previous_location = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overwrite the `__init__` and `save` methods on the model.

```
class Finder(models.Model):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._initial_location = self.location

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.location != self._initial_location
        self.previous_location = self._initial_location
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

In the init method, you keep track of what the initial location was when the object is retrieved from the database. In the save method you check to see if the location is now different and if it is you assign the initial location to the previous location.

Note that this method will not work if you do an update from a queryset. Neither will the pre-save signal method.

Comment: Your method has worked for me. Your code has some mistakes that I have fixed and also added the functionality that if initially the data is "", then do not update the details. Check out my modifications.

`def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self._initial_location != "":
            if self.location != self._initial_location:
                self.previous_location = self._initial_location
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)`

Edit, I'm sorry about the formatting, not sure how to fix that

Answer (score 0):

you can use signals and compare if the location field is changed and add the old value to previous location

```py
def on_change_location(
    sender: Any, instance: Finder, **kwargs: dict
) -> None:
    if instance.id is None:  # new object will be created
        pass
    else:
        previous = Finder.objects.get(id=instance.id)
        if previous.location != instance.location :
        instance.previous_location = previous.location


pre_save.connect(receiver=on_change_location, sender=Finder)
```

tell me if it works, thank you

Answer (score 0):

i found a way around it :

in models:

```
    from django.db import models
    from django.db.models.signals import pre_save,post_save
    from django.dispatch import receiver


    # Create your models here.

    class Finder(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
        location = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
        middle = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="",blank=True)
        previous_location = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="",blank=True)

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(Finder, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.middle = self.location



    @receiver(pre_save,sender=Finder)
    def my_sign(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
        instance.previous_location = instance.middle
```

in admin.py

```
    from django.contrib import admin
    from .models import Finder
    # Register your models here.

    class FinderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        list_display = ('name', 'location','previous_location',)
        exclude =('middle',)


    admin.site.register(Finder, FinderAdmin)
```